# The submit button from same document rendered properly on development server but not on production server

Tags: xpages

I've button which is rendered as designed in test environment. When same document copied to production server which has same configuration as development server does not display it.

Asked the amdin to restart the http task, compact database but nothing worked. The test and production server documents has same configuration.

What to check.

This screen shot is from production database:
[image]

This screen shot is of same document on same server but in Pilot folder:

[image]

Source of submit button:

```
<xp:button
            value="Lab Man Approval"
            id="button4">
            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:document1.isEditable() & (sessionScope.get("flag")==0) & (document1.getItemValueDate("SECTION1DATECOMPLETED")!=null) & (document1.getItemValueString("DOC_STAGE_TX") == "Stage 2") & (@IsMember(@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",document1.getItemValueString("LABManager_NM")),@Name("[ABBREVIATE]",@UserName())))}]]></xp:this.rendered>
            <xp:eventHandler
                event="onclick"
                submit="true"
                refreshMode="complete"
                immediate="false"
                save="true">
                <xp:this.action>
                    <xp:executeScript>
                        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var comboBox2:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspSelectOneMenu = getComponent("comboBox2");
var a=comboBox2.getValue();
var f=sessionScope.get("flag");
if (f == 0){
    sessionScope.put("flag",1);
    }
var f=sessionScope.get("flag");
//sessionScope.put("ITDialog","flag value " + @Text(f));
//var d=getComponent('dialog1');
//d.show();
if (f == 1){
    if ( a=="Accepted"){
    var d=getComponent('dialog2');
    d.show();
    }
    }
if (f == 1){
    if ( a=="More information needed"){
    var d=getComponent('dialog2');
    d.show();
    }
    }
if (f == 1){
    if ( a=="Cancelled"){
    var d=getComponent('dialog2');
    d.show();
    }
    }}]]></xp:this.script>
                    </xp:executeScript>
                </xp:this.action>
            </xp:eventHandler>
        </xp:button>
```

Comment: We need a bit more info here... screenshots?

Comment: Also which browser are you checking with, what does Firebug or some such CSS inspection tool say. Could be something like production server forcing compatibility mode in Internet Explorer, assuming files exist in both places

Comment: Tried all browsers and all have same results.

Comment: I copied production database to test server and button is visible.

Comment: Can you post the source of the submit button to see what it might be doing?

Comment: I second the request for source. Your initial comment was that it wasn't showing the same, which implied CSS. Your screenshots say it's just not showing, which points to the rendered / loaded property. Chances are it's something to do with access, since the button is called "Lab Man Approval".

Comment: I put the code above.

Comment: As Paul said, the problem is the evaluation in the 'rendered' property, it returns false in this case. Maybe a an access or data problem. Try signing the database with server id (also dev version), maybe you used 'sessionAsSigner' somewhere for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got quite a mouthful for your rendered condition, you might want to "outsource" that to a function call. Use something like this and use a computed field to see the result:

```
   function renderApprovalButton(doc) {
        var labManager = @Name("[ABBREVIATE]",doc.getItemValueString("LABManager_NM"));
        var curUser = @Name("[ABBREVIATE]",@UserName());
        /* Take this out when done */
        print(doc.isEditable());
        print(sessionScope.get("flag")==0);
        print(doc.getItemValueDate("SECTION1DATECOMPLETED")!=null);
        print(sessionScope.get("flag")==0);
        print(doc.getItemValueString("DOC_STAGE_TX") == "Stage 2");
        print(labManager);
        print(curUser);
        print(labManager==curUser);
        /* End of debug to be taken out */

        var result = doc.isEditable()
                      && sessionScope.get("flag")==0
                      && doc.getItemValueDate("SECTION1DATECOMPLETED")!=null
                      && sessionScope.get("flag")==0
                      && labManager == curUser; 
        return result;
   }
```

That should do the trick to see what is going wrong

Comment: The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.

Error source
Page Name:/XpPhysicalTestingCoil.xsp
Control Id: computedField23

The above code give error:
Exception
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
Script interpreter error, line=10, col=19: [TypeError] Error calling method 'isEditable()' on an object of type 'lotus.domino.local.Document [Static Java Interface Wrapper, lotus.domino.local.Document: lotus.domino.Document]'
   at [renderValue].renderApprovalButton(725E60317C3256F085257D72005805D6)

Comment: The computed field code <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField23">
     <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:import renderValue;
renderApprovalButton(document1);
}]]></xp:this.value></xp:text>